# Default product URL for a pager

Tags: views, commerce, blocks

Does anyone know how to get around the view error about the default product that doesn't have a URL?

The Commerce module has a default product and  the view pager works without a *More* link, but it errors out with one.

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to do it it turns out.  The workaround is to use the Products format as a Field instead of Rendered Entity and select the "link to this" feature  and set the number of items to display to "zero" - nothing leave blank . . . and change Teaser to default and that will allow the pager to use next controls or a list at the bottom